# File upload but not using form tags in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I want the php script to use the file location for e.g c://documents/file.doc
and read the file then. Here I do not want to use a form tags to upload the file.

I wonder if this is possible.

I will be providing the file path on the hard disk to the php script. Using the script can it read the file for further processing.

Is this possible?

Comment: are your web server and browser on same machine? Or desired file is accessible over network share? If not, it impossible. Read about [client-server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

Comment: So let me see if I understood you want to be able to access `c://documents/file.doc` from a PHP code that is hosted else where not in the same place your computer is and without having to upload the file to it?

Comment: Yes that was my question. But I guess that's not possible right?

Comment: @user3230561 , from other machine
1) it's not possible for path like c://documents/file.doc 
2) it's possible for path like //mymachine/documents/file.doc in local network, if you shared folder c://documents as "documents". 
3) it's not possible in wide-area network

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible obviously, otherwise you could upload whatever you want from user's disk to your server.